# Empty string to NULL or '0' on table creation and file migration - MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have created a table as shown below in MySQL workbench and when importing a file with empty fields in Discount_price it gives me a truncate error and incorrect decimal value, seems its not accepting an empty string to decimal field

-- Errors:

> Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect decimal value: "for column'Discount_Price at row 1", 1366)

-- Original table:

```
CREATE TABLE products (

Project_Name varchar(80),
Unit_Type varchar(80), 
Unit_Total_Price decimal(12,2),
Discount_price decimal(12,2));
```

-- File:

```
Project Name | Unit Type    | Unit Total Price | Discount Price
---------------------------------------------------------------
Product X    | Trial        | 1476300          |
Product X    | Trial        | 1516200          |
Product X    | Trial        | 1635900          |
Product X    | Trial        | 1638000          |
Product X    | Trial        | 1675800          |
Product X    | Commercial   | 1727250          |
Product X    | Commercial   | 1764000          |
Product X    | Commercial   | 1795500          |
```

-- Modified query

I have tried doing the following:

`Discount_price decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL);`

This does not work either error:

> Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect decimal value: "for column'Discount_Price at row 1", 1366)*/

`Discount_price decimal(12,2) as (NULLIF(Discount_price,'')));`

This does not create the table error:

> Code 3107. Generated column can refer only to generated columns defined prior to it.

None did actually work

I have also tried changing the Discount_price type to double type giving the same issue

Note: I do not want to change the type to varchar(..) as I'm planning or doing arithmetic calculations

any idea on how to how to overcome, I do not want to go with several steps so what can be done when creating the table

Comment: Please share more details, like sample data. Also, please share how this is related to MySQL Workbench itself, or remove that tag

Comment: There is a lot of options. You may edit the source file and add `0` value into last column for each row. You may use custom LOAD DATA statement for data importing. You may create string-type Discount_price column, import data, set empty values in the column with zero or NULL then alter the datatype with according query.

Comment: To me it seems that there is something wrong with your data or with the parameters you use to import the file.

Comment: @Akina I don't want to edit the source files as I have hundreds of them it would be time wasting. I have also set the coulmn default to 0 and Null but did not work. I also need to keep the type as decimal as I'm expecting numbers in similar files

Comment: *I have also set the coulmn default to 0 and Null but did not work.* DEFAULT value is applied only when the column is not mentioned in INSERT query at all (exclusion - autoincrement), if it is mentioned (or the columns list is absent) then DEFAULT is ignored anycase. So use 2nd option - custom LOAD DATA statement.